# How do I get my div container to fit the size of my table without scrolling?

Tags: css, html-table, resize, containers, nowrap

**To make sure I am as clear as possible, I have a master page that contains a content place holder.  Inside of content place holder I have a table.  I want the table to be large enough to allow all of the content in the columns to be on one row, but I don't want it to be any larger than that.  Once the table is the appropriate size, I want the container/page to shrink onto the table so there is no random white space.  Anyone have any ideas on how this is suppose to be done properly?**

What I have tried:

I have a master page with a content place holder.  I set up the div that contains the content place holder with

```
style="display:inline-block"
```

This shrinks the container to the size of the whatever is inside of the content place holder.  This worked perfectly fine until I wanted to reformat my table that was inside of the content place holder.  I didn't like how the shrink was forcing the elements in my table to wrap to a new line any time there was white space.  So I added

```
style="white-space:nowrap"
```

to my individual columns and this gave me the desired effect of having all my columns occupy one line/row, and the container was shrinking well onto my table until I finished the last

```
style="white-space:nowrap"
```

on my last column.  What I realized is that the container wasn't changing size based on if I was using

```
style="white-space:nowrap"
```

or not.  The container had already shrunk a fixed amount and every time I made a column wider by preventing the wrapping, the table would come closer and closer to boardering the edge of my page.  Then when I unwrapped my last column the table went over the page.  I added

```
style="overflow:auto"
```

and that allowed me to see my entire table but I don't want to have to scroll, and there is plenty of room for the page to stretch in the window to accomodate my table without scrolling.  I have also done

```
style="width:100%"
```

but that doesn't give me the effect I want because then the container doesn't shrink at all around the table and I feel the table is way too wide at that point.  I also tried

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

but that had no effect.

Thanks

P.S.  Here is my content place holder code

```
    <div style="padding-left:40px;float:left;">
        <table class="table table-bordered; span7">
        <%--<col span="4" style="width:auto; white-space:nowrap" />--%>
            <caption style="padding-top:20px; font-size: xx-large">
                <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" ForeColor="#003a6f" BackColor="#fcf8e3"
            Text="Companies"></asp:Label></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <%--<th>
                    User ID
                </th>--%>
                    <th style="">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="#003a6f" Font-Bold="true"
            Text="Company&nbsp;ID"></asp:Label>

                    </th>
                    <th style="">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" ForeColor="#003a6f" Font-Bold="true"
            Text="Company&nbsp;Name"></asp:Label>

                    </th>
                    <th style="">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#003a6f" Font-Bold="true"
            Text="Company&nbsp;Phone"></asp:Label>

                    </th>
                    <th style="">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ForeColor="#003a6f" Font-Bold="true"
            Text="Company&nbsp;Status"></asp:Label>

                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%  Project1.Master m = new Project1.Master();
                    m.Companies = m.viewCompanies();

                    int count = 0;
                    foreach (Project1.Company c in m.Companies)
                    {
                        if (count % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            //Response.Write("<tr><td>" + u.userID + "</td>");
                            Response.Write("<tr class=\"info\"><td style=\"color:#003a6f; white-space:nowrap\">" + c.companyID + "</td>");
                            Response.Write("<td style=\"white-space:nowrap\">" + "<a class=\"btn-link\" href=\"Company.aspx?cat=" + c.companyName + "\">" + c.companyName + "</a>" + "</td>");
                            Response.Write("<td style=\"color:#003a6f; white-space:nowrap\">" + c.companyPhone + "</td>");
                            Response.Write("<td style=\"color:#003a6f; white-space:nowrap\">" + c.companyStatus + "</td></tr>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Response.Write("<tr class=\"warning\"><td style=\"color:#003a6f; white-space:nowrap\">" + c.companyID + "</td>");
                            Response.Write("<td style=\"white-space:nowrap\">" + "<a class=\"btn-link\" href=\"Company.aspx?cat=" + c.companyName + "\">" + c.companyName + "</a>" + "</td>");
                            Response.Write("<td style=\"color:#003a6f; white-space:nowrap\">" + c.companyPhone + "</td>");
                            Response.Write("<td style=\"color:#003a6f; white-space:nowrap\">" + c.companyStatus + "</td></tr>");
                        }
                        count++;
                    }%>
            </tbody>
        </table>            
    </div>
```

P.S.S.  Relevant Master page code:

```
    <body style="background-color: #003a6f;text-align: center;">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="display:inline-block">
                <div class="row-fluid" style="background-color:White">
                    <div class="span10">
                        <!--Body content-->
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        <br />
                    </div>                
                 </div>
             </div>    
         </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do it seems was add this line of code to the div's that surrounded my tables

style="display:table"